Vite isn't deduping Babel helpers, resulting in output bloat
I want to use @docsearch/react, which (unfortunately) compiles all of its modules in isolation with Babel, meaning, each module has helpers inserted. These helpers all have the same names across modules, however, so they should be able to be deduped.
Here's my usage in Vite:
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { DocSearch } from '@docsearch/react';

function App() {
  return (
    <DocSearch
      appId="YOUR_APP_ID"
      indexName="YOUR_INDEX_NAME"
      apiKey="YOUR_SEARCH_API_KEY"
    />
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)

Building this (vite build) will result in a module that has 10 copies of the _nonIterableRest() helper, easily identified by searching for "Invalid attempt to destructure...".
Why is Vite not deduping these? Am I doing something wrong? Or how can I fix it if this lib is doing something it shouldn't be? Unfortunately it is made up of dozens of modules, so I can't really recompile it all myself.
